# For loop for ports in multiple remote servers in Linux

Tags: linux, script, java, multiple-instances

My program need to run in multiple remote servers with different ports in script, here is an example:

In server 1, need run:

```
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9001
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9002
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9003
              .
              .
              .
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9020
```

In server 2, need run:

```
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9021
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9022
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9023
              .
              .
              .
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9035
```

...

So for creating the script more convenient, how to use a for loop in each server script to run multiple commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server 1:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 20)
do
  java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9${i}
done
```

server 2:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 21 35)
do
  java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9${i}
done
```

while

```
seq -f <format> <first> <last>
```

uses a `printf` style format string. The format must be suitable for printing one argument of type `double`. It can contain a conversion specification consisting of:

- `%`: Introduces the conversion specification
- `0`: The converted value is padded on the left with zeros rather than blanks (optional)
- `3`: Decimal digit string (with nonzero first digit) specifying a minimum field width (optional)
- `g`: Print argument of type `double` in floating point or exponential notation. Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears only if it is followed by at least one digit. (This allows us to print a `double` which looks like an `integer`)

For more details see:

```
man seq
man 3 printf
```

Comment: Thank you, I forget to mention, here need to run those commands at the same time, so how to modify the for loop?

Comment: I figure out it, just add & behind the java command. Thank you for your help. But what's the mean of %03g ?

Comment: Add an `&` after the command to send it to the background.

Comment: Thank you. But what's the mean of %03g ? It means "00x" in the port?

Comment: @Andi yes exactly, it tells `seq` to use the right format (to add zeros on the left) see also my updated answer.